# Units converter without many if statements

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

I'm starting to learn typescript in electron (the professor wanted it that way, its a really cool dude) and was doing a unit convertor that he let me as homework, I managed to make it work with the use of a lot of "if" statements but i wanted to know if theres a way, function or method (im pretty sure there is but couldnt find anything) to improve this code and dont use this many "if", or use them at all. Thank you

HTML (uses a input box to capture the data, 2  (1 from, 1 to unit).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="unidad-box">
        <div id="ingresa-Box">
            <input id="input-number" type="number">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
    <div id="selecciones">
        <p>Seleccione la unidad para convertir</p>
        <select id="input-val">
            <option value="Kilobyte">Kilobyte</option>
            <option value="Megabyte">Megabyte</option>
            <option value="Gygabyte">Gygabyte</option>
            <option value="Terabyte">Terabyte</option>
            <option value="Pentabyte">Pentabyte</option>
          </select> 
          
          <p>Seleccione la Unidad a Convertir</p>

          <select id="output-val">
            <option value="Kilobyte">Kilobyte</option>
            <option value="Megabyte">Megabyte</option>
            <option value="Gygabyte">Gygabyte</option>
            <option value="Terabyte">Terabyte</option>
            <option value="Pentabyte">Pentabyte</option>
          </select> 
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="resultado-box">
            <div id="resultado1-Box">
                <p id="restultadoFinal">El Resultado es:</p>
            </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
<div>
    <div id="button-Box">

        <button id="Convertir">Convertir</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Typescript: (i only included 1 if statement, but it repeats for each option in the select

```
//Retrives the html elements
const nameInput = document.getElementById("input-number") as HTMLInputElement; 
const inputVal = document.getElementById("input-val") as HTMLSelectElement; 
const outputVal = document.getElementById("output-val") as HTMLSelectElement; 
const submitButton = document.getElementById("Convertir"); 
//Main Function( it includes another 4 ifs for each option but didnt put them to save space)
function convertUnits(): void {

  const cantidad = nameInput.valueAsNumber; formato "Float"
  console.log(cantidad);
  const valor = inputVal.value;
  console.log(valor);
  const Conversion = outputVal.value;
  console.log(Conversion);

  if (isNaN(cantidad)) { //Chechs input value
    alert("Favor de ingresar un numero valido");
    return;
  }
  if (valor == "Kilobyte") { //Checks the selected option and converts it to bytes
    let BtKb = cantidad * 1024; //Convierte lo escrito de "Kilobytes" a "Bytes"
    console.log(BtKb);
    if (Conversion == "Kilobyte") { //Chechs the selected option to convert, multiply bytes for the desired value
      var resultado = BtKb / 1024;
      const resultadoF = document.querySelector('#restultadoFinal')!;
      resultadoF.innerHTML = `El Resultado es: ${resultado}`;
    }
    if (Conversion == "Megabyte") {
      var resultado = BtKb / Math.pow(1024, 2);
      const resultadoF = document.querySelector('#restultadoFinal')!;
      resultadoF.innerHTML = `El Resultado es: ${resultado}`;
    }
    if (Conversion == "Gygabyte") {
      var resultado = BtKb / Math.pow(1024, 3);
      const resultadoF = document.querySelector('#restultadoFinal')!;
      resultadoF.innerHTML = `El Resultado es: ${resultado}`;
    }
    if (Conversion == "Terabyte") {
      var resultado = BtKb / Math.pow(1024, 4);
      const resultadoF = document.querySelector('#restultadoFinal')!;
      resultadoF.innerHTML = `El Resultado es: ${resultado}`;
    }
    if (Conversion == "Pentabyte") {
      var resultado = BtKb / Math.pow(1024, 5);
      const resultadoF = document.querySelector('#restultadoFinal')!;
      resultadoF.innerHTML = `El Resultado es: ${resultado}`;
    }
  }
  console.log("salio del if");
}
submitButton!.addEventListener("click", convertUnits); //Button that calls the function every time the user wants
```

I'm sorry for the spanish variables but didnt want to break the code by changin them all thanks.

Comment: I would read up on arrays.

Answer (score 2):

HTML select are designed to be value/label pairs. So you can do, on both input and output sides:

```
   <select id="output-val">
      <option value="10">Kilobyte</option>
      <option value="20">Megabyte</option>
      <option value="30">Gygabyte</option>
      <option value="40">Terabyte</option>
      <option value="50">Pentabyte</option>
   </select>
```

I've chosen to use the value that 2 is raised to, but you can use a different convention. The code is straightforward:

```
  const multiplier = Math.pow(2, inputVal.value - outputVal.value)
  const resultado = nameInput.valueAsNumber * multiplier
```

E.g. if 5 Megabyte to Kilobyte, inputVal.value is 20, outputVal.value is 10, multiplier will be 2^10, and the answer will be 5 x 2^10 = 5120 Kb. If 5  Megabyte to Terabyte, multiplier will be 2^-20, so answer will be 5 x 2^-20 = 0.000004768 Tb.

The other key reason to do it this way is that internationalization is now easy: you change the labels in your HTML, but the values stay the same, so the logic stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an object that maps each unit to their respective power:

```js
const conversionPowerMap = {
    "Kilobyte" : 1,
    "Megabyte" : 2,
    "Gygabyte" : 3,
    "Terabyte" : 4,
    "Pentabyte": 5,
}
```

Then inside your function, just use the key to get your power:

```js
if (valor == "Kilobyte") { //Checks the selected option and converts it to bytes
    let BtKb = cantidad * 1024; //Convierte lo escrito de "Kilobytes" a "Bytes"
    console.log(BtKb);

    // power will be '1' if 'Kilobyte', '2' if 'Megabyte' etc..
    const power = conversionPowerMap[Conversion]

    const resultado = Btkb / Math.pow(1024, power)
    const resultadoF = document.querySelector('#restultadoFinal')!;
    resultadoF.innerHTML = `El Resultado es: ${resultado}`;
}
```

This of course assumes that the `outputVal.value` is restricted to only be one of the keys of `conversionPowerMap`.